# Defining different opentype fonts for title and main text in a beamer theme

Tags: beamer, fonts, font-encodings, opentype

I am working on amending the helpful jhsph beamer theme (https://github.com/jfiksel/jhsphbeamer ) to match my university's font guidelines. The guidelines call for using Quadon for titles, headlines, etc., and Arnhem for most body text.

I can use fontspec easily enough to redefine the sans font to Arnhem:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\setsansfont{Arnhem Pro Bln}
```

and that produces a passable presentation, but of course all text is in Arnhem in one or another size.

I can also use beamer commands to change font classes, e.g.:

```
\setbeamerfont{title}{...}
```

but I've not found a way to combine these two. I've tried, for example:

```
\newfontfamily\quadonmed{Quadon Medium}
\newfontfamily\arnhem{Arnhem Pro Bln}

\setbeamerfont{title}{quadonxb}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{quadonmed}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{quadonmed}
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{arnhem}
```

and the simpler

`\setbeamerfont{title}{Quadon Medium}`

but neither of these works.

I would appreciate advice on how to use different opentype fonts for the title and main text of beamer, and/or any links to themes that use that kind of style.

Comment: Try `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\quadonmed}` (I don’t have the font, but similar cases seem to work).

Comment: Thank you Therese - I think that works!